# Azure file storage use

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am using RMM solution to push a script out to and install a specific software package and it is about 500MB in size. My initial thinking was to create Azure File storage and as a part of the script, it would mount it to each device, copy over the file to local and then install it, after installation, unmount the drive.

Not sure if this is the best solution as there might be approx 1000-5000 devices connecting and mounting at the same time, same file share, would that be ok? I don't have any experience with the limitations of Azure.

Does anyone know a better way this should require a secure connection and the file should not be publicly available.

Note: usually some packages are hosted on developer sites so I can do simple invoke in PowerShell, but this time I am looking for some solution for the future.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ISPs block SMB mapping to Azure files over WAN. Use Azure blob storage with a SAS to download via https instead. You'll have to update the SAS portion of the URL as often as you set it to expire.